# gapi.auth2 can not get access_token

Tags: javascript, google-client, google-client-login

I'm trying to implement resumable uploads for youtube using the javascript client API. I've managed to get the login working using the `g-signin2` button, but I can't get the access_token to send with the requests. This is how I render the sign in button:

```
<span
  class="g-signin2"
  data-onsuccess="youtubeUploaderSigninCallback"
  data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube">
</span>
```

And I'm using the following script files loaded from google (I can't seem to get one working without the other)

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js" async defer></script>
```

I'm using code edited samples from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#upload_video for resumable uploads using XHR.
But these examples use the auth functions marked as deprecated here: [https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs][2])
So the main thing I changed is using the `auth2` and `g-signin2` instead of `result.access_token` and `g-signin`.

So I've been trying to use the `auth2` functions to get the access tokens, but the `access_token` property is undefined when I execute the following code

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse()
```

The way I'm trying to get the access token is documented here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors#making-authenticated-requests

So these are my options, I guess:

1. find a way to get the access token out of the user object

   - (I found that user.hg.access_token contains the token I need
   - but "hg" seems a minified property to me
   - so I'm not intending to use this as it might change with updates
   - **EDIT**: as pointed out in the comments `hg` is a minified property indeed and now no longer exists
2. add progress events to gapi.client.request()

   - but the xhr object doesn't seem to be exposed
3. use code documented as deprecated

Can anyone help me with this? I've been looking for an acceptable solution for a few hours and I feel like crying now... all alone and desperate.

Thanks in advance,
Robbe

PS: [I've also posted this question on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-javascript-client/jR2J79pW9wM)

Comment: FYI: I am now using the "g-signin" button (not g-signin2) and everything works, but I don't know if this is very future proof. So answers are still welcome.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck in finding an answer. According to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetauthresponse, the AuthResponse is supposed to have an access token. Strange that it's not there.

Comment: I implemented the same thing with `g-signin2`, and I _did_ use `hg`, but it proved you right: the property is gone now and and is renamed to `Zi`. Still looking for a way to properly fetch it from the response.

Comment: For now I'm just sticking with the `g-signin` option. This is still working and I hope it stays that way until `g-signin2` is "fixed". Glad I did not depend on the `hg` property. Thanks for sharing, I'll put this in the question.

Answer (score 13):

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token
```

Comment: To improve your answer, you should add some explanation of what your answer does, how to use it and how it answers the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50864432/
`getAuthResponse(true)` 
without `true` the access token is undefined

Comment: Thanks for the above comment!  most documentation doesn't include the `true` parameter.  That solved my problem